# Right way of using conditional expressions on order_by django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using [Case method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) from conditional expression example docs and I found some answers on SO to order `contacts` by `status_text` or `status`, in this example I'm using `status_text` field. I'm doing all of this in my api `get_queryset` and I'm doing something like this,

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = LeadContact.objects.none()
    user = self.request.user
    # I have some other conditions here

    # This is the conditional expressions that I'm building for order_by
    case_sql = LeadContact.objects.annotate(
        custom_order=Case(
            When(status_text=LeadContactConstants.STATUS_CLIENT, then=Value(1)),
            When(status_text=LeadContactConstants.STATUS_QUALIFIED, then=Value(2)),
            When(status_text=LeadContactConstants.STATUS_CONTACTED, then=Value(3)),
            When(status_text=LeadContactConstants.STATUS_PRISTINE, then=Value(4)),
            output_field=CharField(),
        )
    ).order_by('custom_order')

    return queryset.extra(select={'status_text': case_sql}, order_by=['status_text'])
```

Now the database is throwing this Traceback:

```
Traceback:

    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
      58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
      87.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
      466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
      463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
      42.         page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in paginate_queryset
      172.         return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/pagination.py" in paginate_queryset
      303.         return list(queryset[self.offset:self.offset + self.limit])
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
      162.         self._fetch_all()
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
      965.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
      238.         results = compiler.execute_sql()
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
      840.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
      98.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/home/vagrant/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
      124.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
      205.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
      36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

    Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /api/sales/lead_contact/
    Exception Value: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[<LeadContact: Liam Higgins>, <LeadContact: Juraj  Polerecky>, <LeadContact: Pau' at line 1")
```

model field that I'm using for this condition are this two fields, like I said I also tried to use `status` but the error is more less the same:

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LeadContactConstants.STATUSES, default=LeadContactConstants.STATUS_PRISTINE)
status_text = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', blank=True)
```

and the `LeadContactConstants` model is:

```
class LeadContactConstants(object):
    STATUS_PRISTINE = "PRISTINE"
    STATUS_CONTACTED = "CONTACTED"
    STATUS_QUALIFIED = "QUALIFIED"
    STATUS_CLIENT = "CLIENT"

    STATUSES = ((STATUS_PRISTINE, "Virgin"),
                (STATUS_CONTACTED, "Contacted"),
                (STATUS_QUALIFIED, "Qualified"),
                (STATUS_CLIENT, "Client"))
```

I'm not sure how to deal with this, so can someone explain me what is happening and how can I fix this, so I can order my contacts properly, thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you're passing that to `.extra()`. That's not how it works: `case_sql` is the queryset itself, you should just return it.

Comment: ok I've misunderstand some stuff from the docs, but now the order is changing my `status_text` to numbers from the values, and it still not ordering things, when I go `return.order_by('case_sql')`, what else am I doing wrong here

Comment: I'll accept the answer, but I'm still in the process of solving why did this change my `status_text` to number